# jQuery .load() help UPDATED

Tags: jquery, html

I'm still learning jQuery so I have no idea what's going on here but I'm using a filtering script I found on css-tricks and trying to load content into the divs on click but I'm getting `undefined` in the url.

I did this on a part of the page that isn't affected by the filtering script and it worked, so I just need to figure out whats conflicting.

Can anyone please help!

So this is my jQuery to load content in the `div`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#target').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#target').empty();
        $('#target').load('project1.html');
    });
});
```

This is the html:

```
<div id="target">
    <div class="sixteen columns clearfix thumbnail photoeditor">
        <div class="two-thirds columns alpha">
            <img src="images/d1.png" class="scale-with-grid" alt="fieldlazer" />
        </div>
        <div class="one-third columns omega">
            <span class="title">Title goes here</span>
            <span class="details">Description goes here</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the filter jquery script:

```
(function($){
    // Shuffle function from: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/shuffling-the-dom/

    $.fn.shuffle = function() {
        var allElems = this.get(),
            getRandom = function(max) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
            },
            shuffled = $.map(allElems, function() {
                var random = getRandom(allElems.length),
                    randEl = $(allElems[random]).clone(true)[0];
                allElems.splice(random, 1);
                return randEl;
            });

        this.each(function(i){
            $(this).replaceWith($(shuffled[i]));
        });

        return $(shuffled);
    };
})(jQuery);

$(function(){
    $(".thumbnail")
        .css("opacity","0.7")
        .hover(
            function() { $(this).css("opacity","1"); }, 
            function() { $(this).css("opacity","0.7"); }
        )

        $("#allcat").click(function(){
            $(".thumbnail").slideDown();
            $("#catpicker a").removeClass("current");
            $(this).addClass("current");
            return false;
        });

        $(".filter").click(function(){
            var thisFilter = $(this).attr("id");
            $(".thumbnail").slideUp();
            $("."+ thisFilter).slideDown();
            $("#catpicker a").removeClass("current");
            $(this).addClass("current");
            return false;
        });

        $(".thumbnail").shuffle();
});
```

Any help would be really great. Thanks!

EDIT: Alternatively I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#target').click(function(){

var link = $(this).attr('rel');
event.preventDefault();
$('#target').empty();
$('#target').load(link);

});
});
```

with the html:

```
<div id="target" class="sixteen columns clearfix thumbnail photoeditor" rel="404.html">
<div class="two-thirds columns alpha">
<img src="images/d1.png" class="scale-with-grid" alt="fieldlazer" /></div>
<div class="one-third columns omega">
<span class="title">Title goes here</span>
<span class="details">Description goes here</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Still to no avail.

EDIT: ANOTHER UPDATE

SO I kind of got it working but it only works for the first div (Project1) and when I empty the the DIV of the external html and put back the contents of #main-content it's displayed weird and none of the functionality works.
Any suggestions?

Here's the new Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#portfolio div').click(function(event){

var link = $(this).attr('rel');
event.preventDefault();
$('#main-content').load(link);

$("#back").live("click", function(event){
$('#main-content').empty();
$('#main-content').load('index.html #main-content *');
}); 
});
});
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="main-content">
<ul class="tabs-content">
<li class="active" id="portfolio">


<ul id="catpicker">
<li class="active"><a href="#" id="allcat" class="current">View All</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="photoeditor" class="filter">Photo Editor</a></li> 
<li><a href="#" id="producer" class="filter">Producer</a></li></ul>

<div class="sixteen columns thumbnail photoeditor" rel="project1.html">
<div class="two-thirds columns alpha">
<img src="images/d1.png" class="scale-with-grid" alt="fieldlazer" /></div>
<div class="one-third columns omega">
<span class="title">Project 1</span>
<span class="details">Details go here</span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="sixteen columns thumbnail photoeditor" rel="project2.html">
<div class="two-thirds columns alpha">
<img src="images/d1.png" class="scale-with-grid" alt="fieldlazer" /></div>
<div class="one-third columns omega">
<span class="title">Project 2</span>
<span class="details">Details go here</span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="sixteen columns thumbnail photoeditor" rel="project3.html">
<div class="two-thirds columns alpha">
<img src="images/d1.png" class="scale-with-grid" alt="fieldlazer" /></div>
<div class="one-third columns omega">
<span class="title">Project 3</span>
<span class="details">Details go here</span>
</div>
</div>


</li>
<li id="words">
</li>
</ul>
</div><!-- main content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an error on the prevent default line, and that's because you forgot to pass in the event.  Pass in the event to the .click function like this.

```
$('#target').click(function(event)
```

After that it worked for me.